# How can I set a Laravel configuration dynamically based on the currently authenticated user?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using GrahamCampbell's wrapper of the Gitlab API and it has configuration variables for token, and method. The token being the secret token used to authenticate against the api, and method being the type of authentication used. I am using oauth, so my method is set to 'oauth.'

However that token is either generated by a request or stored as an encrypted string in my database on the user model in the oauth workflow

where can I feed that oauth token into the gitlab config in the user login workflow to allow me to make requests to the api on behalf of the currently logged in user?

Obviously, I can't just set the config item to 'token' => $user->gitlab_token, as the config is accessed before most of the laravel classes exist.

Or am I incorrect in any of my assumptions?

Comment: why don't you store it in session?

Comment: @Kristian Where would I store it in session so that it's accessible in the config? I wish there was a way to pass it in to every individual call rather than global config files.

Comment: @Kristian Found the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this, in my case, came from the issues (https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-GitLab/issues/27) on the package I am using. You should use the factory to pass the config in when you make the call.

```
    $gitlab = GitLab::getFactory()->make([
        'token' => $user->gitlab_token,
        'method' => 'oauth',
        'url'     => 'http://git.company.com/api/v4/'
    ]);
    $projects = $gitlab->projects()->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are multiple ways to do this. I'll offer an alternative:

When a user is authenticated via the session the [`Authenticated`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Auth/Events/Authenticated.php) event is fired, therefore you can listen for this and set the token accordingly. In your `EventServiceProvider` add:

```
Event::listen(Authenticated::class, function (Authenticated $event) {
    config([ 'gitlab.token' => $event->user->token ]);
});
```

This will ensure the configuration is updated when a user is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with listener or middlewares .
in php your app run even you call the Web Server than you can change configs in every api call and other client not effect this .
@apokryfos answer is good.